# Different background color to each group in XAML gridview not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

In windows store app (c# & XAML), I'm able to apply same background color to all groups in gridview like this.

```
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="GroupItem">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#28F7E3">
</Setter>
</Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

And above code is working fine. The same thing I want to apply with "binding" mechanism (as I want to apply different background color to each group) and I coded like this

```
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="GroupItem">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding GroupColor}"> 
</Setter> 
</Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

But this is not applying. In XAML world can we apply binding to ContainerStyle element? How to achieve this?

How I'm doing is
1) Created Sample windows store "GridApp". It will generate some files. I opened SampelDataSource file.2) Created one new property 'GroupColor' and setted different background color values 3) Binded to Gridview Container groupstyle XAML as I mentioned above.

Update1:

If I do same thing for GroupStyle HeaderTemplate element its applying as expected for the groupelement. Here is code for GroupHeader datatemplate.

```
<GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid Margin="0">                                      
<Button Background="{Binding Path=GroupColor}" Content="{Binding MyGroupName}"></Button>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

But same thing is not working for Style property Binding. I'm not getting any error. Its just not appending any background color what i'm binding.

Comment: What's the binding error it's giving you? Its most likely that either your `DataContext` is incorrect, so it can't find the property `GroupColor` to bind to, or `GroupColor` is not of the expected data type (`Brush`)

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for your response. I'm not getting any error. And this GroupColor binding is working for some other elments where I placed in Group Header datatemplate for testing purpose.(Updated my post with Update1). Event i tried to Convert to proper datatype like Brush in Style element but no luck.

Comment: Try using a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check out what the `DataContext` is for your `GroupItem` at runtime. It will also highlight any runtime binding errors for you.

Comment: Hi Rachel, I installed Snoop in my windows 8 machine. But not working as expected (may be I'm not correctly using this tool). Will this tool support for windows 8 metro apps?

Comment: I'm not positive, I haven't tried it on Windows 8. I know there are two versions and the 32bit version isn't compatible with 64bit operating systems. An alternative to Snoop is [WPF Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/), but I've never tried this one personally, I've only heard about it.